# Django + uwsgi + nginx . Import error: No module named py

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am trying to run my sample django application using uWSGI and nginx. But I am getting import error, no module named py. I am not sure where should I  add the python path.

I am running with the following command.

```
sudo uwsgi --socket mysite.socket --module wsgi.py --chmod-socket=666.
```

I even tried passing  path in the parameter `--pythonpath`, still the same error.

This is how my wsgi.py looks like

```
enter code here

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I try running, I get the following messages

```
ubuntu@ubuntu1204desktopi386:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysite/mysite
$ sudo uwsgi --socket mysite.socket --module wsgi.py --chmod-socket=666 
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.18.1 (32bit) on [Mon Oct 14 13:15:19 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 13 October 2013 02:53:51
os: Linux-3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013
nodename: ubuntu1204desktopi386
machine: i686
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysite/mysite
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3846
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address mysite.socket fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:26:19)  [GCC 4.6.3]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x9644d68
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 64024 bytes (62 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ImportError: No module named py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 2311, cores: 1)
```

Comment: In any of your files have you done something like `import something.py` ?

Comment: No. It was because I was passing a python file for `--module wsgi.py`. It should be just a module, `--module wsgi`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `--module` argument is presumably meant to be a Python module, not a file. So you probably just need `--module=wsgi`.

Answer (score 4):

i guess you can also use , --wsgi-file wsgi.py like this

```
 $ uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 --wsgi-file my_proj/wsgi.py
```

Make sure you run command from same folder

Answer (score 2):

If `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8024` can work well, then

This also can work(run it on the same directory as above command):

```
uwsgi --http :8024 --module mysite.wsgi
```

`mysite` is the name of this django project

uwsgi version is `2.0.14`;
django version is `1.10`.

ref: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html